# Problem with scraping and saving data using Xpath and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

So Im trying to scrape information about rate, level, duration, certification and save them in csv file. First of all, I don't know if I'm doing it right because I am totally new in Selenium and I don't have idea how to save it correctly in one csv file. All information comes from this site: [here is the link](https://alison.com/course/global-islamic-finance-and-banking). I was trying to use below code but it didn't work:

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/bin/geckodriver")

driver.get('https://alison.com/course/global-islamic-finance-and-banking')

rate = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"course-banner")]//li[2]//div[2]')

level = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"Academic - Third Level - Level 1")]')

duration = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"course-brief-container")]//div[contains(@class,"course-brief")]//li[1]//div[2]')

certification = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"course-brief-container")]//div[contains(@class,"course-brief")]//li[3]//div[2]')
```

I want to **scrape** these data and save at the csv file.

Do you have any idea how to **scrape** this thing? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The correct verb is scrape not scrap ;) Also what is your problem scraping or saving to CSV?

Comment: when I have rate,level,duration, certification from this site and I can print them in terminal I don't know how to save this information in csv file

Comment: Did you search for python libraries specifically scraping websites? I am wondering why you would use Selenium for this task. If you need to click buttons on the target website it might be OK to go with it.

Comment: Yeah, I need to click buttons on the target website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put exact xpath of the element from which you are trying to extract the text. In you code xpath are not exact to the target element. You can try as below.

Note that rate value is combined text and you will have to remove `Rated` text from it.

```
driver.get("https://alison.com/course/global-islamic-finance-and-banking")
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='course-banner--info']/li[2]/div[2]/h4")))
rate =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='course-banner--info']/li[2]/div[2]/h4").text
level = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='course-banner--info']/li[3]/a/div[2]/span").text
duration = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='course-icons']/div[2]/h3[contains(text(),'Duration')]/following-sibling::span").text
certification = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='course-icons']/div[2]/h3[contains(text(),'Certification')]/following-sibling::span").text

print(rate)
print(level)
print(duration)
print(certification)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question. Do you know how to save result in csv file?

Comment: @sid9715 csv is a text file you can have it created before hand and append it with new data as shown here. https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-append-a-new-row-to-an-existing-csv-file/